# Confirmation Url comes up as a string in Hotmail

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, simplemembership, postal

I have this in my Account Controller Register:

```
var token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                model.UserName,
                model.Password,
                    new
                    {
                        model.Email
                    },
                true);

var confirmationUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
        "/Account/ConfirmAccount/" + token;

dynamic email = new Email("RegisterConfirmation");
email.To = model.Email;
email.UserName = model.UserName;
email.ConfirmationUrl = confirmationUrl;
email.Send();
```

Usually i expect that to send out a link to emails and its doing so when sent to a `GMail` and `Yahoo` account, but when sent to a`Hotmail` account the link is sent as a plain `string` which would require copy and past to navigate there.

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect its something to do with hotmail.

If you want, you can instead flag the email as html (email.IsHtml= true I believe) and write it in html, which should work with everything.